# How to use a private members from static methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I would like to use a private (static) method from a public static method in JavaScript. I was looking into this solution:

```
function Calc() {
    var DoSmth = function (test) {
        return test + 1;
    }
}

Calc.Stat = function (x) {
    return DoSmth(x);
}
```

But it wont work. How do I do such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

```
var Calc = (function() {
    var DoSmth = function (test) {
        return test + 1;
    };

    var klass = function() {

    };

    klass.Stat = function (x) {
        return DoSmth(x);
    };

    return klass;
})();
```

Comment: Probably the best way to do this. And this will be really **static** method without need to create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a module pattern:

```
var Calc = (function() {
  var run = function() { ... },
      stat = function() { return run(); };
  return { stat: stat };
}());

Calc.stat();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do private function in JS is to wrap it with another function. I suggest something like this:

```
var Calc = (function() {
    var DoSmth = function (test) {
        return test + 1;
    };

    var result = function() {

    };

    result.Stat = function (x) {
        return DoSmth(x);
    }

    return result;
}());
```